# Connecting VS2005 with SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, sql-server-2012

I had an old project in vs.net 2005 using VB. with rldc reports. So i had to make a change in the report, so when i try to update the DB connecion i got an error message: "Failed to add column"... This server version is not supported. You must have Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Beta or later. First, i googled and i'd found an article telling me to install VS2005 SP1. I did it, but the message is still appearing. So, anyone had this problem? Is there a SP for make working VS2005 with sql sever 2012? What Can i do?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: I am also interested, Did you able to solve your issue ?

Comment: No my friend... I don't have another thing to do than migrate to VS2011, wasting time...